# PrimeNg Error: Quill is not defined

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I am trying to use the editor control in primeng: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor

But I am getting the error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: Quill is not defined
>       at Editor.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/editor/editor.js.Editor.ngAfterViewInit

My project uses:

- Angular Cli: 1.4.1
- Angular: 4.3.6
- NPM: 5.4.1
- Node: 6.10.0
- PrimeNG: 4.2.0

I found this issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/807

I followed the instructions:

## import editor module

```
import {EditorModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

## Install packages:

```
npm install quill --save

npm install @types/quill --save
```

## Update angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [ "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css", "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css", ], "scripts": [ "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js" ],
```

but it still has the same issue.  I am just adding default markup:

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="text" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
```

And I get the error and it looks like this:

[image]

The only thing on that thread I didn't try is installing the webpack plugin because I am using angular cli I don't think that is an option.

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any idea for it init testing for this control?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Was it an imports order issue?

Answer (score 16):

Try This: it's working for me perfectly

**Versions:**

```
Node : 7.9.0
angular/cli: 1.3.0
angular: 4.3.6
npm: 4.2.0
primeng": "^4.2.0-rc.1"
```

install node module quill

```
npm install quill --save
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
  "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"
]
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { EditorModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        EditorModule
    ]
})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="text" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
    text: string;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This looks identical to what I did. I cannot see the difference

Comment: Are you using same versions as me?

Comment: I tried rc1, same issue.  I guess I must have a conflict in my project. I wil try to isolate

Comment: Uninstall following npm primeng, quill and @type/quill and clean npm cache clean then install Oly primeng and quill npm ... Don't install @type/quill ... Try it

Comment: It's also working for me your versions npm, node, cli etc

Comment: This works great in my Chrome browser but i get a "ERROR ReferenceError: 'Quill' is undefined" in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is with the PrimeNG documentation

I was getting "doesn't exist" errors and after looking through the logs I found the path was wrong... (for Angular9 anyway).

PS: this assumes you have installed quill with npm BTW

In the angular.json script and styles section remove the "../" (as defined in the primeng docs) so it reads...

```
    "styles": [
      "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
      "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"
    ]
```

It compiles now and fixed it for me.

Not sure if this is a Windows thing but the "../" was telling the compiler to looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Or "scripts": ["./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"]

Answer (score 2):

Resources of quill needs to be added to your application. Example setup with CLI is as follows;

> npm install quill --save

Add Quill to scripts in **angular.json**

```
"scripts": [... "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"],
```

Add Quill css to styles in **angular.json**

```
"styles": [ ... "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css", 
"node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"],
```

I have checked this solution multiple times with new and existing projects, it works like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

When I was reading the awnswer and after try commands like

```
npm install quill --save
npm install
```

I added Quill to scripts ans css in angular.json

```
"styles": [
          ...
          "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
          "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          ...
          "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"
        ]
```

And using cmd in the project directory

```
npm install quill --save --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was the following:

replace this:

```
import {EditorModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

for this:

```
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';
```

or

```
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/components/button/button';
```

*This way you avoid import all components defined in `primeng/primeng.js.`
So if you are not using chart or editor modules then Chart.js or quill.js are not used and you can avoid to add this libraries in the bundle.*

for more info: [Github Issues](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7769#issuecomment-499117792)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, for fixing this error I did two things:

1. `npm install quill --save`
2. I changed the styles and scripts section of the angular.json file like this

   "styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
   "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
   ],
   "scripts": ["node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"]